# Ability to set CertificateID for LCM with February powershell 5

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to update my DSC deployment to now use partial configurations to break up the configuration. For that I need to now use a pull process instead of push.

When I try to apply the configuration for the LCM which looks something like:

```
[DscLocalConfigurationManager()]
Configuration CreateGESService
{
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()] 
    [PsCredential] $InstallCredential,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()] 
    [PsCredential] $RunCredential
)

Node $AllNodes.NodeName
{

    $hostVersion = (get-host).Version
    # changed how the possible values for debugMode in the February build
    if (($hostVersion.Major -ge 5) -and ($hostVersion.Minor -ge 0) -and ($hostVersion.Build -ge 9842)){
        $debugMode = 'All'
    }
    else{
        $debugMode = $true
    }
    #setup the localConfigManager
    Settings 
    {
         #CertificateID = $node.Thumbprint
         # slower performance - and only available WMF5
         # now we need to kill the dsc
         DebugMode = $debugMode
         ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyAndAutoCorrect'
         ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins = '15'
         AllowModuleOverwrite = $true
         RefreshMode = 'Push'
         ConfigurationID = $node.ConfigurationID
    }

    PartialConfiguration GetEventStoreConfiguration {
        Description = "Contains the stuff for GetEventStore Being Installed"
        ConfigurationSource = "[ConfigurationRepositoryShare]ConfigSource"
        RefreshMode = "Pull"
    }

    PartialConfiguration ExternalIntegrationConfiguration{
        Description = "Contains the stuff for External Integration"
        ConfigurationSource = "[ConfigurationRepositoryShare]ConfigSource"
        DependsOn = '[PartialConfiguration]GetEventStoreConfiguration'
        RefreshMode = "Pull"
    }

    PartialConfiguration ServeGroupSpike{
        Description = "Contains the stuff for External Integration"
        ConfigurationSource = "[ConfigurationRepositoryShare]ConfigSource"
        DependsOn = '[PartialConfiguration]ExternalIntegrationConfiguration'
        RefreshMode = "Pull"
    }

    ConfigurationRepositoryShare ConfigSource{
        SourcePath = "\\someServer\Shared\dscService\Configuration"
        Credential = $InstallCredential
    }

    ResourceRepositoryShare ResourceSource{
        SourcePath = "\\someServer\Shared\dscService\Resources"
        Credential = $InstallCredential
    }
}
```

If I try to include the CertificateID I get an error like:

```
The property CertificateID of metaconfiguration is not compatible with the current version 2.0.0 of the configuration
document. This property only works with version greater than or equal to 1.0.0 . In case the version is greater, then
the property MinimumCompatibleVersion should be set to atleast 1.0.0 . Set these properties in the
OMI_ConfigurationDocument instance in the document and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4
    + PSComputerName        : SGSpike-Main
```

Naturally when the Configuration is attempted to be applied it can't decrypt the credentials passed, and I get an error in the event view like:

```
Job {B37D5239-EDBA-11E4-80C2-00155D9ACA1F} : 
WarningMessage An error occured while applying the partial configuration [PartialConfiguration]ExternalIntegrationConfiguration. The error message is : 
The Local Configuration Manager is not configured with a certificate. Resource '[File]GpgProgram' in configuration 'ExternalIntegrationConfiguration' cannot be processed..
```

Any ideas how to do this? I had this working with the certificateID when I was using a single configuration in a push model.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the April 2015 drop the problem still seems to exist. Further diagnosis shows that you can:

1. Not use partial configurations
2. Not use a certificate to encrypt credentials

Opened an issue on connect (with some more details) at https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/1292678